# R pairwise post-hoc to get contrasts of contrasts for interaction?

Tags: r, lme4, posthoc, lsmeans

I'm running a mixed-effects model in R and I want to know if there is code I can run to get contrasts of contrasts for an interaction for post-hoc testing.

A. Ie. the tukey test I'm running at the moment is this:

There are 2 regions (ML and HG) and 3 treatments (Low_control, Frog and High_control).

```
L.S <- pairs(lsmeans(juvweightmodelfeb6th, ~ Region*Treatment_three))
test(L.S, adjust = "tukey")
```

B. Which gets me these comparisons in the output:

```
HG,Low_control - ML,Low_control   
 HG,Low_control - HG,Frog           
 HG,Low_control - ML,Frog          
 HG,Low_control - HG,High_control   
 HG,Low_control - ML,High_control   
 ML,Low_control - HG,Frog           
 ML,Low_control - ML,Frog           
 ML,Low_control - HG,High_control   
 ML,Low_control - ML,High_control   
 HG,Frog - ML,Frog                 
 HG,Frog - HG,High_control          
 HG,Frog - ML,High_control          
 ML,Frog - HG,High_control          
 ML,Frog - ML,High_control          
 HG,High_control - ML,High_control
```

C. But what I really want is these three comparisons, which are essentially contrasts of contrasts:

```
1. HG, Low_control - HG, Frog    -                 ML, Low_control - ML, Frog

2. HG, High_control - HG, Frog     -               ML, High_control - ML, Frog

3. HG, High_control - HG, Low_control     -   ML, High_control - ML, Low_control
```

D. How do I code for the above three contrasts in a post-hoc test for a mixed-effects model in R?

Thank you!!

Comment: `multcomp::glht` might be the most flexible way to do this

Comment: Hi @Roseanna did you get the comparison to work?